# Transfer SATA signal on USB Type C

Tags: usb-c

USB type-c has alternate mode now. DP, MHL, Thunderbolt, and HDMI signals could be transfered over USB Type C cable directly.

My question: is it possible to transfer SATA signal (preferrably 6 Gbps 3.0) over USB Type-C cable? The main concern is the impedance matching for high speed signals.

The USB Type C specification seems to allow developers to define their own alt mode. I had seen some examples from TI's documents. So this is probably not an issue.

Comment: Usb impedance is lower than sata impedance (90 vs 100 ohms), so you should either change the terminating resistors or add another 5 ohms in series for each line. I think it would work, though I'm not sure what the point is.

Comment: These already exist, and are [quite cheap](https://www.newegg.com/p/1BK-04YS-00067?Description=sata%20bridge&cm_re=sata_bridge-_-9SIASJTDHC4216-_-Product). It doesn't just transfer the raw signals over the line, though; it uses a special protocol for USB-connected hard drives, that gets translated to SATA at the other end of the cable.

Comment: SATA is 100 ohms +/-10%, so 90 ohms is a close enough match that it should work fine. That said, not sure if SATA is a defined alternate mode for USB3. Given that this would only apply to a hard drive, and adaptors are so cheap, why bother?

Comment: And as of this writing, no host controllers seem to offer SATA as an alternate mode. NVMe, yes, but not SATA.

Comment: @hacktastical it may be useful in some special occasion. One situation is to replace the old esata connector and cables with usb-c; another one is it could actually pass two lanes of sata signal, the bandwidth is much higher than a single usb-to-sata bridge ic + sata multipliers. This is useful for disk enclosue with more than one disks inside.

Comment: SATA only supports one lane per device, up to 6Gbit/s for Gen3. USB3.1 at one lane is even faster than that (10Gbps), and adaptors are really cheap. Not worth it.